# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException with Prepared Statements

Tags: java, mysql, exception, sqlexception

I just started learning about MySQL and I am now trying to learn prepared statements. When I uses them, I get this error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException`. Can someone tell me where am I getting the syntax wrong? Thanks. Here is my code:

```java
public class DBConnector {
    
    private Statement statement;
    private ResultSet result;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    public void createDB() { 
            try {
                sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ?";
                tableName = "test_name";
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, tableName);
                int myResult = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    
                if(myResult == 1){
                    System.out.println("Database successfully created.");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Database with that name already exists. Please try again with different name.");
                    createDB();
                }
            }catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Database creation failed.");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what is your use case, but creating database in application code is not advisable unless you are creating a database management application like phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

We can't bind Database names in Query parameters.

```
Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 

int rs=stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE dbname");
```

Try in this way, Database will create.

Comment: Didn't know that! Thank you so much!

Comment: it works but l cant set custom names that way... I wanted to give the user freedom to set his own db name. Thx anyways.

Comment: String sql = "create database " +obj.getDbName(); you can pass in this way as well